# Android BufferedReader ReadLine() got IOException - Expected a hex chunk size , How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, readline, bufferedreader, ioexception

I`m using BufferedReader in Android to receive http stream connection , when parse message I received use code:

```
url = new URL(HOST_URL_PUSHMESSAGE);
urlConnection = url.openConnection();
in = (InputStream) urlConnection.getContent();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
line = reader.readLine();
in.close();
```

It looks work well but Sometime I got IOException - Expected a hex chunk size,but was..
Happened in:

```
line = reader.readLine();
```

How does this happen & How can this be resolved?
Does change bufferedreader size help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the source
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/ChunkedInputStream.java.htm
 The exception happens there

```
try {
    bytesRemainingInChunk = Integer.parseInt(chunkSizeString.trim(), 16);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IOException("Expected a hex chunk size, but was " + chunkSizeString);
}
```

Looks like something incorrect in the data.